# SDL2/GL context defaults to v3.0 on linux mint

Tags: linux, opengl

When I compile & run my code to create an opengl 3.3 or above context (identical to the windows version, with one or two extra lines), it defaults to 3.0, which will cause problems with some of my applications I want to port over.

I'm looking for a fix/explanation of this.

Source as follows:

```c
//Using SDL and standard IO
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
//Screen dimension constants
const int SCREEN_WIDTH = 640;
const int SCREEN_HEIGHT = 480;


bool handleEvent(SDL_Event& event)
{
    return true;
}



int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    //The window we'll be rendering to
    SDL_Window* window = NULL;


    //Initialize SDL
    if( SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_VIDEO ) < 0 )
    {
        printf( "SDL could not initialize! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {


    //Create window
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL/GLM/OpenGL Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
    SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
    if( window == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Window could not be created! SDL_Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError() );
    }
    else
    {
        SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
        SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
        SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1); // set swap buffers to sync with monitor's vertical refresh rate


        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
        glClearColor(1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0);
        GLenum err = glewInit();
        if (err != GLEW_OK)
        {
            printf("glew init failed: %s!\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        }
        printf("opengl version :%s\n",glGetString(GL_VERSION));
        bool running = true; // set running to true
        SDL_Event sdlEvent;  // variable to detect SDL events
        while (running)
        {   // the event loop
            while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdlEvent))
            {
                if (sdlEvent.type == SDL_QUIT)
                    running = false;
                else
                {
                    running = handleEvent(sdlEvent);
                }

            }
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window);
        }
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
}


    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set GL attributes *before* you create a window, not after you create a context:

> [`SDL_GL_SetAttribute()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute)
>
> Use this function to set an OpenGL window attribute **before window creation**.

Example:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );

    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow
        (
        "SDL2", 
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
        300, 300, 
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL
        );
    if( NULL == window )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create window: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_Quit();
        return 0;
    }

    SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    if( NULL == context )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to create GL context: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    if( SDL_GL_MakeCurrent( window, context ) < 0 )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed to make GL context current: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext( context );
        SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << "GL_VERSION: " << glGetString( GL_VERSION ) << std::endl;

    SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1);

    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if( GLEW_OK != err )
    {
        std::cerr << "Failed init GLEW: " << glewGetErrorString( err ) << std::endl;
        SDL_GL_DeleteContext( context );
        SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
        SDL_Quit();
        return -1;
    }

    bool running = true;
    while( running )
    {
        SDL_Event ev;
        while( SDL_PollEvent( &ev ) )
        {
            if ( ev.type == SDL_QUIT )
                running = false;
        }

        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow( window );
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext( context );
    SDL_DestroyWindow( window );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When I move the SDL_GL_SetAttribute() lines to before window creation, as you suggest, glewinit fails with a missing GL version error

Comment: @IanYoung: Verify that [`SDL_GL_CreateContext()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_CreateContext) and [`SDL_GL_MakeCurrent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_MakeCurrent) succeed.

Comment: If you mean like this:

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);

        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

  //Create window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL/GLM/OpenGL Demo", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
        SDL_GLContext context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
        SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, context);

it fails

Comment: @IanYoung: Be advised that `glewInit` may leave the OpenGL context with nonzero error state. This is a bug of GLEW, the issue is known for years and until it gets fixed your only course is to ignore it and flush the OpenGL error state after GLEW initialization.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, mesa drivers do not support OpenGL contexts above 3.0, so the driver will default to the maximum available, which is 3.0. In order to create a 3.x context, you must have proprietary drivers installed. Once I had installed those drivers everything worked fine.

Comment: That is not true. Mesa does support modern GL in core profiles only. genpfault's answer explained what you have to do. The fact that glew did not work any more after you followed his advice actually indicated that it did work as intended. GLEW just has a bug with core profiles. If you use your original code with the proprietary drivers from AMD or NVIDIA, you'll most likely get a _compatibility_ profile, where GLEW works without hacks.